# Extract specific Type from a Record<string, Type> in Typescript

Tags: typescript

Consider a type `PageProps : Record<string, Type>`:

```js
type PageProps = Record<
  string,
  | {
      type: "title";
      title: Array<{
        type: "text";
        text: {
          content: string;
          link: {
            url: string;
          } | null;
        };
        plain_text: string;
        href: string | null;
      }>;
    }
  | {
      type: "rich_text";
      rich_text: Array<
        | {
            type: "text";
            text: {
              content: string;
              link: {
                url: string;
              } | null;
            };
            plain_text: string;
            href: string | null;
          }
        | {
            type: "equation";
            equation: {
              expression: string;
            };
            plain_text: string;
            href: string | null;
          }
      >;
      id: string;
    }
  | {
      type: "number";
      number: number;
      id: string;
    }
  | {
      type: "url";
      url: string;
      id: string;
    }
>;
```

How can I extract below type from the above `PageProps : Record<Keys, Type>`:

```js
type RichText = {
      type: "rich_text";
      rich_text: Array<
        | {
            type: "text";
            text: {
              content: string;
              link: {
                url: string;
              } | null;
            };
            plain_text: string;
            href: string | null;
          }
        | {
            type: "equation";
            equation: {
              expression: string;
            };
            plain_text: string;
            href: string | null;
          }
      >;
      id: string;
    }
```

I tried [Pick](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys) and [Extract](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) but couldn't get it to work for `Record<Keys, Type>`.

Try this in [TS Playgroud](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACghgcwjATgezAZygXigJQgGM0UATAHgFgAoKKTYFASwDsEAaW+gHygG9u9YaEgAuKACJgzYABsIkgNxDhUGfIgSAgihRwQFQXTUjwWqcAgAPYMtWmrticdOmSrK54mMW7FSZu9HJsANYuDkFQAK4ocj5MbAgBUfQAvlB8rNFycilBafluYHJwbAD6TsAJfsmRwgAWKBAAZjVJmVDZuUXCaQB8vWlCfK6O5hKSLEQNlTZ2vfTTs1U6egbUgaaj9W6iFtLz9ltRqwK7QR5e1QyJ-hduIazh5yep9LHxt7WLqRlZOTyDz6v2KpQqZ18SVBpiarXa7E63SBbzUw1RnTG732kwgAEdonAZGhWMd3vR8YTiawIhi3DYwM1MJhmCSEXU6SDgfQSmVWHNnN9odyoHC2kLEQCesD0W5BvVmGR2UMRq89hMpNkALYAIwgKDJpm1epQEmN+t+iuVDllmPqOKkn0Nak+1reVolHLRtHlNCAA)

> Note: `PageProps` comes from a module so it's not possible to edit/refactor it.

Comment: I've tried a similar thing with chart.js once and I couldn't find a solution for this. So you might be lost here.

Comment: `type X<T, K extends string> = T extends { type: K } ? T : never` and then `type RichText = X<PageProps[string], "rich_text">` or a variation of that should work. I'm on mobile and can't really test or verify, so not writing up an answer for it. Having a separate helper type is important here as it distributes over the discriminated union.

Comment: @IngoBürk that actually worked!

Comment: There's actually an easier solution using built-ins.

Comment: haha yes, that's even neater.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get access to this part of the discrimnated union like this:

```js
type RichText = Extract<PageProps[string], {type: "rich_text"}>;
```

This essentially relies on the fact that `PageProps[string]` is a discrimnated union and makes use of the fact that TypeScript distributes over union types used as generic type arguments.